# Error " invalid -j parameter" while running "make px4_sitl_default gazebo"

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu, px4

I am running command "make px4_sitl_default gazebo" on Ubuntu18.04(VM) to work with px4 and gazebo,  I install all dependencies as shown in http://docs.px4.io/master/en/simulation/gazebo.html
however, I am getting the below error every time. I didn't see anybody who takes this kinda failure all forums, so I thought somebody can help me here.

```
[837/841] Performing build step for 'sitl_gazebo'
ninja: fatal: invalid -j parameter
FAILED: external/Stamp/sitl_gazebo/sitl_gazebo-build 
cd /home/mollaemin/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo && /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/mollaemin/PX4-Autopilot/build/px4_sitl_default/build_gazebo -- -j 0
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Makefile:225: recipe for target 'px4_sitl_default' failed
make: *** [px4_sitl_default] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's trying to run with `-j 0` which means it is trying to do 0 consecutive jobs at once. Instead, you should manually specify how many you would like to run; i.e. `make px4_sitl_default gazebo -j 4`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was using VM for Ubuntu. After various problem I decided to install ubuntu my local drive and it works fine now.